# MySQL data not being added by PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following form that I am inserting in to a database with a primary key called index to give them all a numerical value.  What am I doing wrong that it won't add it?  It doesn't give me an error messages at all.  Thanks for the assistance!

FORM:

```
 <form action = "addissue.php" METHOD = "POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
    <td>Date Issue Occurred:</td>
    <!--http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm-->
    <td><script>DateInput('orderdate', true, 'DD-MON-YYYY')</script></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Please select the application affected:</td>
    <td><select name = "application">
        <option value = "default1">1</option>
        <option value = "2">2</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Start Time:</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "start" /></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>End Time:</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "end" /></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Duration:</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "dur" /></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Service Level Affecting?</td>
    <td><input type = "radio" name = "sla" value = "Yes" />Yes
             <input type = "radio" name = "sla" value = "No" />No</td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>System State:</td>
    <td><select name = "state">
        <option value = "down">Down</option>
        <option value = "degradated">Degradated</option>
        <option value = "feature">Feature Broken</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Issue Description:</td>
    <td><textarea name = "issuedesc"rows = "5" cols = "90">Enter Issue Description Here.</textarea></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Resolution Description:</td>
    <td><textarea name = "resdesc" rows = "5" cols = "90">Enter Resolution Description Here.</textarea></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Group Issue Is Assigned To:</td>
    <td><select name = "group">
        <option value = "default1">1</option>
        <option value = "2">2</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Addissue.php

```
<?php

    include('db_loginreport.php');

    $con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);

    if(!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysql_select_db($db_database);

    if(!$db_select)

    {

        die("Could not select the database. <br />".mysql_error());

    }
    $date = $_POST["orderdate"];
    $app = $_POST["application"];
    $starttime = $_POST["start"];
    $endtime = $_POST["end"];
    $duration = $_POST["dur"];
    $sysstate = $_POST["state"];
    $issdesc = $_POST["issuedesc"];
    $resdesc = $_POST["resdesc"];
    $assigned = $_POST["group"];

    $query = "Insert INTO issuetrack (date, app, starttime, endtime, duration, sla, sysstate,issdesc, resdesc, assigned) 
                        VALUES ($date, $app,$starttime,$endtime,$duration,$sysstate,$issdesc,$resdesc,$assigned)";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result)

    {

        die("Could not query the database:  <br />".mysql_error());

    }

?>
```

db format:

```
#   Column  Type
1   index   int(11)
2   date    varchar(11)
3   app varchar(50)
4   starttime   varchar(16)
5   endtime varchar(16)
6   duration    varchar(5)
7   sla varchar(3)
8   sysstate    varchar(20)
9   issdesc varchar(2048)
10  resdesc varchar(2048)
11  assigned    varchar(30)
```

Comment: Hey, you are **wide open** to SQL injection.  Learn PDO with prepared queries... don't even bother trying to get what you have now working.  You'll be hacked very quickly.

Comment: This is for something internal to my group at work.  I think I would be ok with this.

Comment: @Intelwalk... that's what you think.  Wait until someone sticks an apostrophe in there, or your form gets exposed elsewhere.  It's one thing to be ignorant about the proper ways to do things.  It's a completely different issue to ignore such serious problems.  If you refuse to fix such a fundamental issue, then you really have no business developing for web.  I hope I never have to use a form you make.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm definitely going to go back and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems.  The insert fails because your variables are not enclosed in quotes as in `'$date'`:

```
$query = "Insert INTO issuetrack (date, app, starttime, endtime, duration, sla,  sysstate,issdesc, resdesc, assigned) 
                    VALUES ('$date', '$app','$starttime','$endtime','$duration','$sla','$sysstate','$issdesc','$resdesc','$assigned')";
```

Also, note that you are missing an entry for `$sla` in your query. I have added it above.

Your second problem is that your script is wide open to tampering via SQL injection.

At a minimum, you MUST escape all of these variables with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, even if it is for an internal application only.

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["orderdate"]);
$app = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["application"]);
$starttime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["start"]);
...
...
$resdesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["resdesc"]);
$assigned = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["group"]);
```

Comment: 3rd problem: Assuming the queries succeeded and not having ANY error handling, which would've revealed the sql syntax errors caused by the unquoted data insertion.

Comment: Additionally, there are 10 fields in the list of columns and 9 in the list of values

Comment: @MarcB the error handling is there: `die("Could not query the database:  <br />".mysql_error());`

Comment: Ah ,right... serves me right for not scrolling down far enough.

Comment: @jfkiley Yep,looks like `sla` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect

```
$query = "Insert INTO issuetrack (date, app, starttime, endtime, duration, sla, sysstate,issdesc, resdesc, assigned) 
                    VALUES ($date, $app,$starttime,$endtime,$duration,$sysstate,$issdesc,$resdesc,$assigned)";
```

This is correct

```
$query = "Insert INTO issuetrack (date, app, starttime, endtime, duration, sysstate,issdesc, resdesc, assigned) 
                    VALUES ('$date', '$app', '$starttime','$endtime','$duration','$sysstate','$issdesc','$resdesc','$assigned')";
```

The problem here is that you're trying to add the `$sysstate` into the `sla`, the `$issdesc` into the `sysstate`, the `$resdesc` into the `issdesc` and `$assigned` into `resdesc` leaving `assigned` empty.

edit: updated to include quotes